# Views: How to create a list of OG groups that the current user has edit privileges for?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

How to create a view that lists only organic groups that the current user has edit privileges for?

Each group could be created by different user so filtering by sth like *user: created by* will not work in my case.

I use set up *Access: OG permission | update group* or *Access: Role*

I didn't use any contextual filters nor could find any og/user permissions specific filters so the view shows the list of all groups in the system.

I log in as a non-administrator user/role.
I would prefer a solution that doesn't require custom module coding.